# jquery not working sharepoint subsites

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2010

```
$("div.s4-ctx").bind('click', function () {
    var T = setTimeout(showAlert, 400);
});
$("div.ms-vh-div").bind('click', function () {
    var T = setTimeout(showAlert, 400);
});

function showAlert() {
    $('div.ms-MenuUIPopupBody').css('left', '+=120px');
}
```

`jquery` working fine in sharepoint home page. but it is not working in sharepoint subsites.

Comment: Define not working? Does it throw an error on the console? Vague...

Answer (score 0):

A couple possibilities:

- You are inserting the SCRIPT tag that references the jQuery library on the home page, but not on the sub site pages.
- You are inserting the SCRIPT tag that references the jQuery library on all of the pages but the SRC attribute is relative and only correct on the home page.